Auditing Pipleines in Azure Data Factory
I recently started a Data Engineering role and I was tasked with finding a way to audit our existing pipelines in Azure Data Factory. The requirements are to get all existing components of the pipelines, when they run, if they ran successfully and if any rows were added/deleted to databases after the pipeline ran.
I am able to get most of the information from the pipeline and pipeline runs api but I am not sure how to find out what database tables were updated after the pipeline runs. For now I would just like to get something as basic as a count on each table.
Has anyone done something like this? What is the best approach to achieve this? Can this be done without modifying existing pipelines?
Thank you in advance for helping a noob out. Any help is appreciated :).

You can follow below procedure to get added rows to the SQL database table:
Create string  variable 'prt'  with value @utcNow() with set variable activity. It will store the pipeline run start time. Add activity to insert the rows to the SQL table, here I have taken lookup activity for sample added sql db linked service to it and selected Query option and write some query to add row to the table as below:
INSERT INTO student (Id,Name)
VALUES (6,'FF');select 1 as output;


Add Script or Look Up activity add SQL db linked service, and run the below query to get added rows to the table after pipeline run:
DECLARE @PipelineStartTime DATETIME2 = '@{variables('prt')}';

SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE InsertedAt > @PipelineStartTime;

You will get the output as shown below:

Note: Ensure your SQL table has a column (e.g., InsertedAt) that automatically records the timestamp when a row is inserted. Modify your table according to it.
Alternatively, you can use change data capture(CDC) in mapping data flow to get the changed data including inserted, updated and deleted rows can be automatically detected and extracted by ADF mapping data flow from the source databases. For more information you can refer to the document.
